# Give a file name as a string, remove all dots from it

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char s[50], aux[50], t,ch;

int i,j, size;
printf("Enter the name of your chosen file: ");
gets(s);

size=strlen(s);
ch='.';



for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
if(s[i] != ch)
   {
   t = s[i];
   aux[j] = t;
   j++;
   }
}
aux[j] = '\0';


printf("The name of your file without dot extension indicators is: %s \n",aux);
return 0;


}
```

I made a simple program that takes a file name as an input and returns the file name without the dots. For example, if I enter file.txt.kk.f , the program will return filetxtkkf. I was wondering if it is possible to put each one of the given extensions into its own string and at the end output the name of the file and each extension eg : name: file  extension1: txt , extension2= kk and extension3: f .

Comment: initialize `j` with `0`. `j = 0`. No need of variable `t`, you can directly asign value like `aux[j] = s[i];`.

Comment: avoid using gets, use fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin ) instead

Comment: So you want to tokenize a string on `.` characters. The rest is superfluous fluff.

Answer (score 1):

This program will do the job:

```
int main()
{
    char s[50], *aux[10], ch;
    int i, cnt = 0, size;

    printf("Enter the name of your chosen file: ");
    while(fgets(s, 50, stdin) == 0);

    size = strlen(s);
    ch='.';

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!i)
            aux[cnt] = &s[i];

        if (s[i] == ch) {
            s[i] = '\0';
            aux[++cnt] = &s[++i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= cnt; i++)
        printf("%s\n", aux[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The pointer to the file extension will be stored in aux.
Advantage is that

> 1. Need not use strtok or any other standard functions
> 2. No extra memory is used to make copy of the extensions or store the final result
> 3. Better performance compared to strtok

Answer (score 0):

There is a library function already to do this. Use `strtok_r()` to achieve your goal. Check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

Steps:

1. Take the input.
2. Set the delimiter `delim` as `.` and parse the input filename.
3. The first token will be the name of the file. The second token will be the extension.

<sup>Don't forget to initialize the variables and also check for errors.</sup>

---

EDIT:

Check the below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char input [128] = {0, };
    char saveptr[32][32];
    char * tok = NULL;

    printf("Enter the name of your chosen file: ");
    fgets(input, 127, stdin);

    tok = strtok_r(input, ".", (char **)saveptr);
    if (tok)
    {
        printf("File Name : %s\t", tok);
    }
    tok = strtok_r(NULL, ". \n \0", (char **)saveptr);
    if (tok)
    {
        printf("Extension : %s\n", tok);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**o/p**

```
[sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out 
Enter the name of your chosen file: sourav.txt
File Name : sourav  Extension : txt
[sourav@broadsword temp]$
```

Comment: Ok I will read up on it and try implementing it to my code even though I have never used it before.

Comment: @Module you can check this sample code and adopt as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

How about `memmove`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char s[50];
    memset(s, 0, 50);
    printf("Enter the name of your chosen file: ");
    while(fgets(s, 50, stdin) != 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (s[i] == '.') {
            memmove(s + i, s + i + 1, 50 - i - 1);
        }
    }
    printf("The name of your file without dot extension indicators is: %s \n", s);
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/XqBmae).

When the string contains a dot, it copies everything in the string after the current position to the current position, thus overwriting the dot.

Comment: shouldn't `while(fgets(s, 50, stdin) != 0);` this be `while(fgets(s, 50, stdin) == 0);` ? Cause fgets will return `s` on success and NULL on failure

Comment: On my copy of Ubuntu 14.04: looks like gets() returns NULL on error *or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read*, so I think that this would work. Fundamentally, this is not a very good way of reading input.